# How to parse JSON array from https webpage using proxy and login credentials?

Tags: json, https

Hi I'm a newbie to Android and Java.

I need to parse JSONArray from https://url.com/impact/empid which needs to be accessed with proxy credentials from office network and also the website has to be passed with username and password as login credentials.

Kindly help me with sample code.

Comment: I have tried something like this..

Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
      
       systemProperties.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "proxy.c.com" );       systemProperties.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "6050" );      systemProperties.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "311979");systemProperties.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "!pass");HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true) httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET"); httpConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json");

             httpConn.connect();